# is there a central way for programmatically doing customer account creation in magento?

Tags: magento

i need to override the customer account creation process.

looking at the Customer Account Controller, I see the createPostAction() method where it seems like multiple things are involved in account creation (addresses, etc.)

but what if customer account creation goes beyond just the form? why is this logic so ingrained into the controller?

looking for ideas/suggestions for how to ultimately override customer account creation...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [SOAP API method for creating a customer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/customer#customer.create).

You can also look at the implementation of the SOAP API method

```
File: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php
public function create($customerData)
{
    $customerData = $this->_prepareData($customerData);
    try {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setData($customerData)
            ->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $customer->getId();
}
```

and see where the code that the API calls is run.  This is sufficient for creating a customer.